# Expanding the Twitter Widget width beyond 520px limit : post-March 2016

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter, widget

So I've got an embedded Twitter Timeline on my site, and I'd like it to expand to the full width of the div it's contained in (which is greater than 520px).

I've been searching all day for solutions, which there are a fair amount of, but none have worked for me. Many of the solutions are outdated as it seems Twitter has frequently changed the way their code works with these Widgets. If anyone is able to solve this issue at this current time, I'd love to know how.

Comment: Would be nice if you have also given your website link. I'm a newbie, hence can't find the solution without checking the code and doing some work on it.

Comment: @NewbieDeveloper [www.clubhousegolf.ca](https://www.clubhousegolf.ca/). You'll need to create an account to view it. Twitter timeline will be on your Dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter has improved the responsiveness of the widget and it can now be resized to be larger than 520px without the need for any workarounds. This does however put it into a 'large display mode' which increases the font-size to be rather large which you cannot change. Hopefully they change this soon.

More info on their community pages here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/embedded-timeline-font/64662